# write in the file with Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++

How do I write my input in the file?
Here is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        int fd;
        int x;
        int *y;
        fd=open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT , S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
        cin>>x;
        *y=x;
        write(fd,y, 4);
    }    

    return 0;
    }
```

Maybe there is something wrong with permissions that i give to the file because when i try to open the file from directory it gives this

"There was a problem opening the file “/home/ubuntu/Desktop/file.txt”. The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again."

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using `std::osftream`?

Comment: Looks like plain c code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, there is `cin` involved

Comment: where is `y` declared?

Comment: @Slava Eeek, I didn't spot that within all that shouting file opening options.

Comment: you're writing the value as _binary_ not text, which explains that your text editor complains. But what do you want to do exactly? write as binary or as text?

Comment: I am trying to write the integer that i input into the file

Comment: `y` is a pointer that is dereferenced while uninitialized. Very Bad Things will come of this.

Comment: You have to assign `y` a value *before* you attempt to use its value! Also, why write a pointer to a file?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz looks like he does not know how to get a pointer from `int` variable, this is convoluted way to write `&x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to file name and the fact you are opening result file in a text editor, you suppose to write into text file. On C++ you should use `std::ofstream` instead of `open/write`:

```
    cin>>x;
    std::ofstream fd( argv[1] );
    fd << x << std::endl;
```

that would write number as a text. What you are currently doing is dumping `int` as binary blob, which text editor does not expect to get.

Note: you have to check that `argc>1` so `argv[1]` does have value, otherwise you would get UB. You may check that file opened properly, though in simple app you can ignore that, as writing in such case would not have bad effects (I mean crash or etc).